# Cross correlation in Stata

Tags: stata, assumptions, cross-correlation, cross-section

I have a cross sectional dataset of investment figures (in $) and a set of dependent variables. The data relates to various years (2000-2013).  More than one investment is included in the dataset for any one year (in total there are around 700 investments for the period under consideration)

I am aware that there may be issues of cross correlation in the residuals related to having data related to different years in the same dataset.

I'm not sure how I should go about to test for these or correct this problem?  Running regressions for each year and averaging could be an option?

(PS I use Stata)

Comment: Do you have repeated observations of the same units across time?

Comment: No the observations vary over time, they're different investments!